# Refresh page and change 1 $_GET variable

Tags: php, get, substr, strpos

I've been wondering this for a while since I started PHP. Some sites use filtering options. Sometimes some of those filters are completely random. For example someone might be viewing: `products.php?c=1&p=1&s=100` In that example, let's assume `c` is the category, `p` is the page and `s` is the start price.

If the viewing user were to change the start price or flip to the next page using a hyperlink, how would one change only a single `$_GET[]` variable while leaving the others untouched. I do have a small script in PHP to obtain the current URI however, I just can't figure out how I'd change only that variable while keeping the others untouched and refresh the page? I've looked at `substr()`, `strpos()`, and `ereg_replace()` and I just can't figure it out!

I am really sorry if this is a dumb question, I feel like I've missed something really easy that can fix this but I'm genuinely stuck guys.

Thanks so much in advance!
Mike.

Comment: Great answers thanks guys! The actual problem I'm having is I have a page on my website that display historic events, those that have passed. As such users can go between pages and while sorting is available it is not mandatory. The basic url reads: `history.php?p=1&v=1`. However, if a user activates sorting I want the sort variable to get ADDED onto the end of the URL, so if a user is already at `v=3` which indicates the pages of history they've gone through then I need to add `sort=asc` onto the end of the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you're in a form or a URL.

If you're in a form it's easy because the user changes the input field they want changed and the others stay there:

```
<form>
    <input type="p" value="1" />
    <input type="c" value="1" />
    <input type="s" value="100" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The problem with the URL based method is you would have to set the url for each one like this:

```
<a href="?p=1&c=1&s=1">$1 Starting Price</a>
<a href="?p=1&c=1&s=10">$10 Starting Price</a>
<a href="?p=1&c=1&s=100">$100 Starting Price</a>
```

You'd have to do this to make it dynamic:

```
<a href="?p=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['p']) ?>&c=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['c']) ?>&s=1">$1 Starting Price</a>
```

That's a lot of typing for all of your links. You could make a PHP function to handle changing the one value like this:

```
function genUrl($newKey, $newVal) {
    $url = '?';
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
        if ($url != '?') {
            $url .= '&';
        }

        $url .= urlencode($key) . '=' ($key == $newKey ? $newVal : urlencode($val));
    }

    return $url;
}
```

And your html would look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo genUrl('s', 1) ?>">$1 Starting Price</a>
<a href="<?php echo genUrl('s', 10) ?>">$1 Starting Price</a>
<a href="<?php echo genUrl('s', 100) ?>">$1 Starting Price</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I manipulated your code slightly so that I could pass a key and value to my function, create a $_GET variable from those parameters and then generate the URL that I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Nice code, but you are missing a point after = ;)
$url .= urlencode($key) . '=' . ($key == $newKey ? $newVal : urlencode($val));

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have your hyperlinks location set up to the variable you like to change. Say if it is currently `products.php?c=1&p=1&s=100` and you wanna go to `products.php?c=2&p=1&s=100` then you need to have your anchor tag like so

```
<?php

$_GET['c'] = $_GET['c']++;

?>

<a href='<?php echo "products.php?c={$_GET['c']}&p=1&s=100" ?>'>link<a/>
```

It is identical with other variables.